# NSBundle error Xcode 8

Tags: swift3, nsbundle

I am following a beginner game tutorial online and I got to this point where I am linking a sound file to several buttons.

Here is the code for it:

```
let soundFilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1", ofType: "wav")
let soundFileURL = NSURL(fileIRLWithPath: soundFilePath!)
```

Unfortunately, "NSBundle" is highlighted red and it says "Replace NSBundle with Bundle". I did but then I get the "mainBundle" error and so on.

The tutorial I am following is using Xcode 7.3+ I am Using Xcode 8+ so I'm certain that's the problem. Is there a way I can rewrite the code so it works properly?

Thanks.

Comment: While it may not seem like it, the target is really about the removal of the `NS` prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 3, try this:

```
let soundFilePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "1", ofType: "wav")
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks alot that worked!

Comment: You're welcome. Please remember that if it works, you should mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Done! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3 many Foundation classes have been turned into native Swift structs (missing NS prefix). The benefit is dramatically reduced code and better conformance to the Swift value type semantics.

As you need an URL anyway use the URL related API of `Bundle`

```
let soundFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"1", withExtension: "wav")
```

Unfortunately only a few writers of online tutorials seem to know that :-/

Comment: Hi there, I also tried yours and it worked, less coding too.